# How to configure the search Results Count component in SXA?

Tags: content-search, sxa

I've added a Results Count component to my search results page.

Searching, autocompletion, page selector etc all works perfectly, but I cannot get the Results Count to show a number of found results; it just displays the text I entered in the Results count text field.

I triend adding {0} as a placeholder to the text but to no avail.

Secondly, how do I get rid of the progress bar element shown below?

Thank you so much for your help!

[image: results count not showing number of results, grey progress bar]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Results Count rendering script is looking for `{count}` string in the text you've provided. And it replaces this with the number of results. So type something like: `"The number of results is: {count}"` inside of **Results count text** field of Results Count rendering configuration item.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Thank you! Do you know how to get rid of the progress element I showed in the screenshot? Even when the count is shown correctly this is still rendered.

Answer (score 1):

For the progress bar, you will have to remove it in the ResultsCount.cshtml file or just hide it with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a placeholder for showing some kind of progress/loading animation when fetching the results async.

There is no way of disabling it, so (like most with SXA components), you will have to edit the cshtml or use display:none or someting. This thing really should have been set-up in the rendering variant if you ask me.